# detect if an app has been launched in android

Tags: android

i am using the following snippet (RunningTaskInfo) to show toast if any app besides my project launches However, i cant seem to find a way to whitelist launcher apps. it always shows toast even if my launcher is open and no other app is open. there are hundreds of launchers out there (both stock and 3rd party)

```
public static void getScreenState(Context c){
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) c.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        boolean isScreenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
        if(isScreenOn){
            ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) c.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            List<RunningTaskInfo> runningTaskInfos = manager.getRunningTasks(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
            RunningTaskInfo info = runningTaskInfos.get(0);
            String nowPackageName = info.baseActivity.getPackageName();
            if(nowPackageName.equals("com.example.detectapplaunch")){
            //  return ScreenState.MYAPP;
            }else{
            //  return ScreenState.OTHERAPP;
                Toast.makeText(c, " warning", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
//          Log.e("MyUtils",nowPackageName);
        }else{
//          Log.e("isScreenOn:",String.valueOf(isScreenOn));
            //return ScreenState.LOCK;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `getRunningTasks()` was not only deprecated in Android 5.0, but does not return all the device tasks, for privacy reasons.

Comment: ah thanks. could you explain what "depreciated" means? i used to think depreciated is when there is no support or updates for that library. but now i am guessing, it means certain android versions don't support it. if yes, would it force close on Android 5.0? or just won't work

Comment: "Deprecated" *usually* means that it will continue to work but is not recommended. In this case, quoting [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningTasks(int)): "As of LOLLIPOP, this method is no longer available to third party applications: the introduction of document-centric recents means it can leak person information to the caller. For backwards compatibility, it will still return a small subset of its data: at least the caller's own tasks, and possibly some other tasks such as home that are known to not be sensitive."

Comment: what other alternatives should i consider for writing a "app locker"?

Comment: the concept of an "app locker" (to block or interfere with the launch of another app) is a violation of Google Policy. An app that is designed to be an app "launcher" that does not launch all apps *may* not be, but likely would also violate policy. You will probably violate policy unless you take the approach of an "Administration" app: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html